# Optimized Joined query for large tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I have a project to analyze event logs.
The goal is based on a parent table(Table 1) to compare the timestamps on an interval of 30 seconds.

Table1

```
id                            command                           datetime
---------------------       -------------------               ----------------------
 1                              cat                            2018-11-03 23:29:31
 2                              nmap                           2018-11-03 23:22:32
 3                              ssh                            2018-11-03 23:22:40
```

Event Log Tables

```
    id                              raw                              datetime
---------------                  ------------                  --------------------
     1                              text                         2018-11-03 23:23:10
     2                              text                         2018-11-03 23:23:20
```

So based on table1 datetime i want to output all the event logs that were triggered in a time iterval eg 30 seconds

For now i use this left join statement and it works fine for small size tables (less than 1 MB):

```
    SELECT table1.command as Command,table2.raw as Nginx,Table3.raw as Apache
    FROM Table1
    left join Table2  
    on Table1.datetime::timestamp>= Table2.datetime::timestamp - interval '30 seconds'
    and Table1.datetime::timestamp<= Table2.datetime::timestamp + interval '30 seconds'
    left join 
    Table3  on table1.datetime::timestamp>= Table3.datetime::timestamp - interval '1   seconds'
    and Table1.datetime::timestamp<= Table3.datetime::timestamp + interval '30 seconds'
```

It works fines and gives me the output that i want,the problem is that i have tables with 200K+ rows and the takes a lot of time for the query to be executed,
Is not that is crucial to be really fast but for example if i join 3 tables the (Table1 on the example) and the other 2 table contain 200k+ rows the query time is over 5 hours.

Bellow is an Explain statement to get an idea:

```
     Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..930881273799.88 rows=1202913100267 width=1819)
       Join Filter: ((b1.datetime >= (s1.datetime - '00:00:30'::interval)) AND (b1.datetime <= (s1.datetime + '00:00:30'::interval)))
       ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..60290628.13 rows=36384533 width=1343)
             Join Filter: ((b1.datetime <= s2.datetime) AND (b1.datetime >= (s2.datetime - '00:00:30'::interval)))
             ->  Seq Scan on bash b1  (cost=0.00..75.13 rows=4013 width=34)
             ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..28885.00 rows=81600 width=1317)
                   ->  Seq Scan on suricata__alert s2  (cost=0.00..15089.00 rows=81600 width=1317)
       ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..43131.25 rows=297550 width=492)
             ->  Seq Scan on suricata__http s1  (cost=0.00..22755.50 rows=297550 width=492)
```

Can I optimize the Join Statement? Should I get different approach to the problem (use Views,Indexes?)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the _complete_ execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Are your table have any indexes on datetime fields?

Comment: No there are no indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index can only be used if the `WHERE` condition is of the form

`<indexed expression> <operator> <constant>`

where `<operator>` must be in the operator class with which the index was defined, and `<constant>` doesn't really have to be a constant, but have a fixed value for the duration of the index scan.

So you should rewrite your query to

```
SELECT table1.command AS Command,
       table2.raw AS Nginx,
       table3.raw AS Apache
FROM Table1
   LEFT JOIN table2  
      ON table2.datetime::timestamp
         BETWEEN table1.datetime::timestamp - interval '30 seconds'
             AND table1.datetime::timestamp + interval '30 seconds'
   LEFT JOIN table3
      ON table3.datetime::timestamp
         BETWEEN table1.datetime::timestamp - interval '30 seconds'
             AND table1.datetime::timestamp + interval '30 seconds';
```

Make sure there are indexes on the `datetime` column of `table2` and `table3`.

This might still be slow unless you limit the number of rows that you want to retrieve from `table1` with a `WHERE` condition.